# No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

I was able to load any xhtml page when I was using JSF and then I thought to add spring. I went to the documentation [jsf spring integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html) and added el-resolver in my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
        <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        </application>
</faces-config>
```

now when I am trying to load the page it's giving the error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: No WebApplicationContext found: no
>   ContextLoaderListener registered?
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` listener in your `WEB-INF\web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: great!! error is gone !! but a new problem started.. error 404: The reource is not found.

Comment: Post a new question for the new problem.

Comment: I am trying to post a new question but it's saying I can post only after 90 minutes. Could you please tell me what else I should do to make the page visible?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

1. I was not including  applicationContext in my WEB-INF folder.
2. Spring-asm-3.1.4 was conflicting.

You don't need spring asm if you are using spring version higher than 3.2, as it's included in spring-core. It conflicts with the spring-core and throw other exceptions.