# Not able to resolve the Error [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered? ]

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

i think this issue is already answered but iam not able to figure out what is wrong with the configuration i have added , Before adding authentication "loginform.jsp" added it is working fine but after added that code, it's not working

My requirement is after  login is surpassed it should proceed to the Index Page.

Iam not able to get that loginPage Please help me

[image: Snap of My Project]

Web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringHibernate</display-name>  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringHibernate</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/SpringHibernate-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>


    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringHibernate</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> 
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginForm.jsp</welcome-file>    
  </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

SpringHibernate-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava" />
     <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DAVDB" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="Password123" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/config/studentmessages" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <!-- class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!--    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> -->

    <!--    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager -->

</beans>
```

LoginForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<style>
    .error {
        color: red; font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Spring MVC Form Validation Demo - Login Form</h2>
        <table border="0" width="90%">
        <form:form action="login" commandName="userForm">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Email: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="email" size="30"/></td>
                    <td align="left"><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        </form:form>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Spring3 MVC with Hibernate3 CRUD Example using Annotations</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Spring 3 MVC with Hibernate3 CRUD Example using Annotations</h2>
    <h2>1. <a href="employees.html">List of Employees</a></h2>
    <h2>2. <a href="add.html">Add Employee</a></h2>
    <h2>3. <a href="student.html">Add Student</a></h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Part of the EmployeeController code

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewLogin(Map<String, Object> model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("userForm", user);
    //    return "Cred";

      return "LoginForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
            BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "LoginForm";
        }

      //  return "LoginSuccess";
        return "index";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("command")EmployeeBean employeeBean,BindingResult result){     
        Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);

    /*  if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            return new ModelAndView("save.html");
        }*/

        System.out.println("date-----------"+employee.getDategiven());
        System.out.println("Salary-----------"+employee.getSalary());

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
```

When running tHe code iam  getting the following error...

```
SEVERE: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:239)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.jsp.LoginForm_jsp._jspService(LoginForm_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Mar 21, 2015 12:56:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SpringHibernate] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:239)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.jsp.LoginForm_jsp._jspService(LoginForm_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have gone thru the link but it does'nt resolve my issuse

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015057/no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-contextloaderlistener-registered
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ContextLoaderListener` in web.xml that will load WebApplicationContext. Also move `<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>` out of servlet and use `<context-param>`, like this:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/SpringHibernate-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, i made the changes as u mentioned getting the following  error. 'HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute
type Exception report
message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute 
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Comment: In your` <bean id="jspViewResolver">` you specify the jsp location in <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />, but you put LoginForm.jsp (ang index.jsp) under /WEB-INF, move them into /WEB-INF/views/ or specify path to point them in EmployeeController's return: `return "../LoginForm"`

Comment: Thank you very Much it worked, just one more doubt my as you can see above snapshot the springHibernate-servlet.xml is in WEB-INF/config/ folder.  but when iam running is is showing the Following path  /WEB-INF/SpringHibernate-servlet.xml] SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet SpringHibernate
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringHibernate-servlet.xml] and throwing exception   WHere i need to make the correction ?

Comment: @Learner, Spring uses naming convention "servletName"+"-servlet.xml" to find config xml. For example, if your servlet has a name "SpringHibernate", you must have a xml named "SpringHibernate-servlet.xml" in WEB-INF. So, in your case, if you move the xml file to `/WEB-INF/` from `WEB-INF/config/`, it will work.

Comment: yes when i move out from config to WEB-INF it is working                   but My doubt is why this will not work WEB-INF/config/SpringHibernate-servlet.xml

Comment: I think this is a bug. In my case, I have several xmls in different folder, such as /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/springbean/webBeans.xml, it works for 2nd xml (in different folder), but seems the 1st one must be in /WEB-INF/.